# Is there any advantage to GETDATE() + x over DATEADD(day,x,GETDATE())?

Tags: sql-server

As I understand it, there are 2 main ways to add/subtract days to a date/datetime in MS SQL Server:

For example, to add one day, there is:

- `GETDATE() + 1`
- `DATEADD(day, 1, GETDATE())`

Is there any advantage or disadvantage to either approach?

Comment: with getdate() you can face a problem same date types. except that i think no differences between them. i use getdate but it's better to use dateadd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No real advantages except that when you use GETDATE()+1 we don't really know what you are adding (days, months, hours, seconds?).

DATEADD makes it explicit and also ease your job when you need to add something else than days.

Comment: Unclear and it breaks your code with newer types. Try `DECLARE @d DATETIME = SYSDATETIME()+1;` for example... more details [here](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx) and [here](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mishandling-date-range-queries.aspx) (as well as other shorthand bad habits to avoid).

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion `GetDate()+1` will add just 1 day to current date, there is no way to add months or years in current date, but if you want to add month, year, hours etc o than `DATEADD` provide various [options](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_dateadd.asp) using that you can get past\future dates based on current date.
So if you are trying to add just day, than both would have same impact.

Thanks
Suresh

Comment: Why advocate for the special case when all other cases require DATEADD()? Why not just always use DATEADD()? To save 40 microseconds worth of keystrokes?

Comment: I agree Aaron, better to use DATEADD().